# How to bring Switch Background Image to Front of Switch in Xamarin android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

1. Main.axml Code

   ```
    <Switch
       android:layout_column="3"
       android:text=""
       android:id="@+id/swc_fjr_repeat_single"
       android:paddingLeft="3dp"
       android:layout_width="42.0dp"
       android:layout_height="18dp"
       android:background="@drawable/check"
       android:width="32dp"
       android:height="18dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:checked="false"
       android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
       android:thumbTint="#ff0000ff"
       android:trackTint="#ff0000ff" />
   ```
2. @drawable/check Code :

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <!-- When selected, use selected image -->
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image1"
      android:state_checked="true"/>
      <!-- When not selected, use unselected image-->
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image1"
      android:state_checked="false"/>

      </selector>
   ```

   [image]

> Here the Image is show in Background , and ovverride by the switch Thumb and track. But i want that this image is show in Front of Switch and image ovverride the Switch thumb and track, so how it is possible ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently setting `@drawable/check` as background, so it will be override by thumb, to let it override the thumb, you simply need to set it as `android:foreground`:

```
<Switch
   ...
   android:foreground="@drawable/check"
   android:thumbTint="#ff0000ff"
   android:trackTint="#ff0000ff" />
```